# Ruby on Rails 4 corrupts PDF files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I recently upgraded a Rails 2.3 application to Rails 4. One feature of the app is to upload PDF files which will then be stored in the database. It is also possible to download those PDFs. However, some (about 20%) downloaded PDF files cannot be displayed by the PDF viewer ("PDF document is damaged"). Strange to say I can download the same PDFs from the same database using Rails 2.3 and everything is okay. This leads me to the assumption that the PDFs in the database are not corrupted, but something goes wrong when Rails 4 delivers them.

This is the corresponding code that sends the PDF files:

```
def show_pdf_document
  send_data @files.pdf.binary_data, :filename => @files.pdf.filename, :type =>@files.pdf.filetype
end
```

Might it be an encoding issue?

Update: The problem doesn't seem to be directly related to Rails 4. I have a Unicorn/nginx setup. When I connect directly to the Unicorn worker it works without any problems. It's nginx that seems to corrupt the PDFs.

Comment: What OS?  What is in the `filetype` field?

Comment: Database is Postgresql running on Ubuntu 10.04, as well as the Rails system. Filetype field is "application/pdf"

Comment: Thanks.  What is the type of field `binary_data` in PostgreSQL?  What is the locale?  This is more likely to be a database connection problem than the `send_data`.  If the field is `text` rather than `bytes`, you have it.

Comment: Data type is "bytea". What locale do you mean?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be directly related to Rails 4. I have a Unicorn/nginx setup. When I connect directly to the Unicorn worker it works without any problems. It's nginx that seems to corrupt the PDFs.

Comment: I was about to write that it doesn't look like it could be Rails or PG using bytea.  Looked at the Rails 4 source, and there's nothing there that could change binary data.  One thing to try is to change the MIME type to application/octet.  It's barely possible that nginx is trying to apply some kind of encoding transformation when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had something to do with Unicorn and Nginx. However, I didn't find the exact source of the problem. In this case, the most practical solution was to replace Unicorn/Nginx with Passenger/Nginx. Works like a charm now.